# Force compile (missing source files)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to convert a .jar application into an applet.  I've unpacked the .jar file, found the manifest and identified the main class file.  I've then reverse engineered it and changed the main class to run as an applet instead.  However, it won't compile because I don't have all the source files.  Is there anyway to force a compile?  It looks like it will work from class files but as I understand it the compiler needs all the relevant source files in order to complete.

As always any advice would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should be happy if you can put all the relevant classfiles on the classpath. You should not need the original source.

Otherwise, it would be impossible to use any libraries unless you had the original source!

The classfiles need to be in the correct directory structure to match the package, e.g. class `com.acme.stuff.MyClass` needs to go in `com/acme/stuff`.

Comment: Doh!  Good point.  Thanks for your help.  I'll try thinking before I ask another question  :)